# com.google cannot be resolved using Android Google Maps API V2

Tags: android, google-maps, mapping, google-maps-api-2

I downloaded a tutorial Android project that focuses on using the GPS to create a trail and display it on the screen.

The problem comes with the import statements the project uses:

```
com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
com.google.android.maps.MapController;
com.google.android.maps.MapView;
```

Errors are stating `"the import com.google cannot be resolved"`

I am aware at this point you need to download the Google Play Services library to get the v2 Maps API, but that is about it. I have been searching through posts from 2011-2013 related to this subject and the solutions do not work.

All I am trying to do is update the project so it works with current devices

The project is found here

Manifest: https://code.google.com/p/routetracker2-amasio2012/source/browse/AndroidManifest.xml

Main Activity:https://code.google.com/p/routetracker2-amasio2012/source/browse/RouteTracker.java

Other Classes:

```
// RouteOverlay.java
// Draws route on MapView.
package com.deitel.routetracker;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.location.Location;

import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.maps.Overlay;

public class RouteOverlay extends Overlay 
{
   private List<Location> locations; // stores Location tracking data
   private Paint pathPaint; // Paint information for the Path
   private Paint positionPaint; // Paint information for current position
   private final int POSITION_MARKER = 10; // marker frequency

   public RouteOverlay() 
   {
      // Paint for drawing Path as a red line with a width of 5
      pathPaint = new Paint();
      pathPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
      pathPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
      pathPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
      pathPaint.setStrokeWidth(5);
      locations = new ArrayList<Location>(); // initialize points

      // Paint for drawing black circle every POSITION_MARKER Locations
      positionPaint = new Paint();
      positionPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
      positionPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
   } // end RouteOverlay constructor

   // add new Location to List of Locations
   public void addPoint(Location location) 
   {
      locations.add(location);
   } // end method addPoint

   // reset the Overlay for tracking a new route
   public void reset()
   {
      locations.clear(); // delete all prior Locations
   } // end method reset

   // draw this Overlay on top of the given MapView
   @Override
   public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow) 
   {
      super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow); // call super's draw method
      Path newPath = new Path(); // get a new Path
      Location previous = null; // initialize previous Location to null

      // for each Location
      for (int i = 0; i < locations.size(); ++i) 
      {
         Location location = locations.get(i);

         // convert Location to GeoPoint
         Double newLatitude = location.getLatitude() * 1E6;
         Double newLongitude = location.getLongitude() * 1E6;
         GeoPoint newPoint = new GeoPoint(newLatitude.intValue(),
            newLongitude.intValue());

         // convert the GeoPoint to point on the screen
         Point newScreenPoints = new Point();
         mapView.getProjection().toPixels(newPoint, newScreenPoints);

         if (previous != null) // if this is not the first Location
         {
            // get GeoPoint for the previous Location
            Double oldLatitude = previous.getLatitude() * 1E6;
            Double oldLongitude = previous.getLongitude() * 1E6;
            GeoPoint oldPoint = new GeoPoint(oldLatitude.intValue(),
               oldLongitude.intValue());

            // convert the GeoPoint to point on the screen
            Point oldScreenPoints = new Point();
            mapView.getProjection().toPixels(oldPoint, oldScreenPoints);

            // add the new point to the Path
            newPath.quadTo(oldScreenPoints.x, oldScreenPoints.y,
               (newScreenPoints.x + oldScreenPoints.x) / 2,
               (newScreenPoints.y + oldScreenPoints.y) / 2);

            // possibly draw a black dot for current position 
            if ((i % POSITION_MARKER) == 0)
               canvas.drawCircle(newScreenPoints.x, newScreenPoints.y, 10, 
                  positionPaint);
         } // end if
         else 
         {
            // move to the first Location
            newPath.moveTo(newScreenPoints.x, newScreenPoints.y);
         } // end else

         previous = location; // store location
      } // end for

      canvas.drawPath(newPath, pathPaint); // draw the path
   } // end method draw
} // end class RouteOverlay


/**************************************************************************
 * (C) Copyright 1992-2012 by Deitel & Associates, Inc. and               *
 * Pearson Education, Inc. All Rights Reserved.                           *
 *                                                                        *
 * DISCLAIMER: The authors and publisher of this book have used their     *
 * best efforts in preparing the book. These efforts include the          *
 * development, research, and testing of the theories and programs        *
 * to determine their effectiveness. The authors and publisher make       *
 * no warranty of any kind, expressed or implied, with regard to these    *
 * programs or to the documentation contained in these books. The authors *
 * and publisher shall not be liable in any event for incidental or       *
 * consequential damages in connection with, or arising out of, the       *
 * furnishing, performance, or use of these programs.                     *
 **************************************************************************/


// BearingFrameLayout.java
// Rotates MapView according to device's bearing.
package com.deitel.routetracker;

import com.google.android.maps.MapView;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.view.Display;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;

public class BearingFrameLayout extends FrameLayout 
{
   private int scale = 0; // amount to scale layout
   private MapView mapView; // displays Google maps
   private float bearing = 0f; // compass bearing

   // returns layout parameters for MapView
   public LayoutParams getChildLayoutParams() 
   {
      Display display = 
         ((Activity) getContext()).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
      int w = display.getWidth();
      int h = display.getHeight();
      scale = (int) Math.sqrt((w * w) + (h * h));

      return new LayoutParams(scale, scale);
   } // end method getChildLayoutParams

   // public constructor for BearingFrameLayout
   public BearingFrameLayout(Context context, String apiKey) 
   {
      super(context); // call super constructor

      mapView = new MapView(context, apiKey); // create new MapView      
      mapView.setClickable(true); // allow user interactions with the map
      mapView.setEnabled(true); // enables the MapView to generate events
      mapView.setSatellite(false); // display map image
      mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true); // enable zoom controls

      // set MapView's layout
      mapView.setLayoutParams(getChildLayoutParams()); 
      addView(mapView); // add MapView to this layout
   } // end BearingFrameLayout constructor

   // rotates the map according to bearing
   @Override
   protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) 
   {
      if (bearing >= 0) // if the bearing is greater than 0
      {
         // get canvas dimensions
         int canvasWidth = canvas.getWidth();
         int canvasHeight = canvas.getHeight();

         // dimensions of the scaled canvas
         int width = scale;
         int height = scale;

         // center of scaled canvas
         int centerXScaled = width / 2;
         int centerYScaled = height / 2;

         // center of screen canvas
         int centerX = canvasWidth / 2;
         int centerY = canvasHeight / 2;

         // move center of scaled area to center of actual screen
         canvas.translate(-(centerXScaled - centerX), 
            -(centerYScaled - centerY));

         // rotate around center of screen
         canvas.rotate(-bearing, centerXScaled, centerYScaled);
      } // end if

      super.dispatchDraw(canvas); // draw child Views of this layout
   } // end method dispatchDraw

   // set the compass bearing
   public void setBearing(float bearing) 
   {
      this.bearing = bearing;
   } // end method setCompassBearing

   // return the MapView
   public MapView getMapview() 
   {
      return mapView;
   } // end method getMapView
} // end class BearingFrameLayout


/**************************************************************************
 * (C) Copyright 1992-2012 by Deitel & Associates, Inc. and               *
 * Pearson Education, Inc. All Rights Reserved.                           *
 *                                                                        *
 * DISCLAIMER: The authors and publisher of this book have used their     *
 * best efforts in preparing the book. These efforts include the          *
 * development, research, and testing of the theories and programs        *
 * to determine their effectiveness. The authors and publisher make       *
 * no warranty of any kind, expressed or implied, with regard to these    *
 * programs or to the documentation contained in these books. The authors *
 * and publisher shall not be liable in any event for incidental or       *
 * consequential damages in connection with, or arising out of, the       *
 * furnishing, performance, or use of these programs.                     *
 **************************************************************************/
```

Comment: You are attempting to use code that relied upon the now-obsolete Maps V1 API, which bears little resemblance to the Maps V2 API. I suggest that perhaps you start with a project that is written for Maps V2. IOW, use a project that does not use `com.google.android.maps` classes, but instead uses `com.google.android.gms.maps` classes like `MapFragment`.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thank you for your response. Is there documentation to find the outdated package classes updates or alternatives in the gms package?

Comment: I am not aware of any such official documentation. While there may be some blog posts, etc. on the subject, please understand that the migration from Maps V1 to Maps V2 occurred two years ago. Maps V2 itself has changed since then (though not massively). This is why I would suggest that you start with some sample project that is up to date, rather than try to port this existing code. There are lots of Maps V2 samples online. Here is a directory with nearly 20 of them: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/MapsV2